# Is it bad to short a DC motor for a long time?

Tags: dc-motor, power-consumption, best-practice

I am using one of those small yellow "robot" DC motor like [this one](http://www.averagemanvsraspberrypi.com/2015/12/yellow-motors.html), on a circuit where the motor will turn on a couple of times under certain circumstances.

[image: Yellow motor]

I am thinking of designing a normally-closed circuit where both poles of the motor are shorted at all times to keep it stopped.

When a sensor goes off, one of the poles will be grounded and the motor will spin until the sensor goes on again, shorting the motor and braking it.

My question is: is it bad to keep the poles shorted for a very long period? Both in terms of **damaging the motor** and **power consumption**.

The "very long period" would be 24/7, with the motor turning on for ~5 seconds every 6 hours.

EDIT: Here's the schematic, haven't tested it yet but this is more or less what I'm planning to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frBAku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No good schematic, no good answer.

Comment: Your question is likely irrelevant; spin the motor, remove power, and see that it really doesn't "coast" much at all.  Then notice how hard it is to backdrive.  If you are putting enough torque on it that it actually does backdrive, you should be worried more about mechanical damage than electrical.  An electronic brake is unlikely to be useful with this gearmotor.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Sorry, added the schematics now.

Comment: @Gus - that "schematic" doesn't help your question at all, actually it harms it by badly mismatching your already clear and sensible text.  Even a schematic which showed what you were doing would not include any of the *relevant* information which would be strictly about the electrical and mechanical ratings of the motor and gearbox and nature of the load.  Harry's request for a schematic was pointless, unfortunately we have people like that here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I assumed that a schematic was relevant because of this text "*My question is: is it bad to keep the poles shorted for a very long period?*", which is heavily dependent on the topology used for driving the motor.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - no, it's not dependent on that at all.  When the poles are shorted, nothing upstream matters *to the motor* which is the *subject of the question*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmm, I suppose you're right - I was thinking more of burning transistors or what not, I missed the part where gus said that he was planning on using a NC circuit. Oh well. - Guess I wasn't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorting a motor by itself is no problem.  It only becomes a problem if external forces turn the motor shaft fast enough to cause too much dissipation in the motor.  When the motor is shorted, all the mechanical power from external things driving its shaft ends up getting dissipated in the motor as heat.  As long as the motor can handle that heat, there is no problem.

It should take no power electrically to keep the motor shorted.  You can keep a FET on across the motor using no power.  It's only when switching that FETs take control power.

Make sure that the wussy little plastic gears in the yellow part can handle the stresses of the external torque working against the shorted motor.  Of course if those torques are within what the motor itself is rated to put out, it should be fine in theory.  The reason I only "in theory" is that on cheap motors with plastic gearboxes optimized for price, the motor's full torque for extended periods of time may damage the device too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights! I don't think the mechanical power from external things in the shaft (a disc in my case) will be a problem because they're not stopping immediately, but I'll definitely run tests for extended periods and see if there is any damage done to the motor or the disc.